# How to bind a GridView from code behind and update the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I check many sites and referred many codes before I could post a questions here. I am facing lot of confusions seeing them. Here is my problem.

I have a `GridView` and I have bound it from code behind as :

```
public void BindData()
{
    SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Label2.Text + "", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

And my asp.net for the same looks like :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ForeColor="#333333" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="Locations" 
                onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Locations">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblLocations" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Locations") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lamp_Profile1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblLamp_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Lamp_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblEditLamp_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Lamp_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fan_Profile1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblFan_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fan_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblEditFan_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fan_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AC_Profile1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblAC_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AC_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblEditAC_Profile1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AC_Profile1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And I have written my `GridView1_RowCancelingEdit` like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
```

And my `GridView1_RowEditing` looks like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

And my `GridView1_RowUpdating` looks like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.RowIndex;

    Label Locations = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("LblLocations") as Label;
    //ViewState["Locations_Instance"] = Locations.Text;

    Label Lamp_Profile1 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("LblLamp_Profile1") as Label;
    Label Fan_Profile1 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("LblFan_Profile1") as Label;
    Label AC_Profile1 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("LblAC_Profile1") as Label;

    string query = "UPDATE " + Label3.Text + " SET Lamp_Profile1 ='" + Lamp_Profile1 + "', Fan_Profile1 ='" + Fan_Profile1 + "', AC_Profile1 ='" + AC_Profile1 + "' WHERE Locations = '" + Locations + "'";
    com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    BindData();
    //lbldisplay.Text = "Updated Successfully";
}
```

**From this I am getting what ever row I am binding using template field as well as database columns in my `GridView` and Once I click on Edit in the `GridView`, the whole `GridView` disappears.**

Please help me.

Comment: What problem or error do you have?

Answer (score 1):

if you call BindData in page load then do that:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    BindData();
```

That might solve your problem...

Cheers

Comment: Since I am binding the `GridView` from `Label2`, until the `Label2` text is generated, I cant use in if (!IsPostBack). It is giving me an error invalid `Label2`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the textbox that is generated on edit event in the **RowUpdating** event below and assign it to a string variable.

Then have a seperate function to update the values entered and finally call your BindGrid() function which again binds the gridview..

Note: I'm using stored procedure to update my DB table.

```
protected void grdKeywords_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdKeywords.Rows[e.RowIndex];
       TextBox txtKeyword = row.FindControl("txtGridKeyword") as TextBox;
       string keyword = string.Empty;
       keyword = txtKeyword.Text;
       UpdateKeyword(keyword.ToLower());

    }



public int UpdateKeyword(string strKeyword)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmdUpdateKeyword = BuildCommand(conn, "proc_UpdateKeyword");
        cmdUpdateKeyword.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keyword", strKeyword);
        conn.Open();
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmdUpdateKeyword.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
        BindGrid();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To manually specify columns for the gridview you have to set  **AutoGenerateColumns="false"**. Now you can specify the columns that you want in your GridView. You can use both "BoundFields" & "TemplateFields" now. As shown below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="column1" HeaderText="Column1" SortExpression="" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="column2" HeaderText="Column2" SortExpression="" />
            <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="points">
            <HeaderTemplate>HELLO</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hello") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now you can use:

**GridView.RowDataBound Event** to bind data to the data row.

```
 void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      Label Label1= ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1"));
      Label1.Text = "YOURDATA";

    }

  }
```

Comment: The void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) is written only if I use template fields...?

Answer (score 0):

```
public int UpdateKeyword(string strKeyword)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmdUpdateKeyword = BuildCommand(conn, "proc_UpdateKeyword");
    cmdUpdateKeyword.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keyword", strKeyword);
    conn.Open();
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmdUpdateKeyword.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close();
    BindGrid();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have EnableViewState="true" set in your GridView. It solved disapperance-issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.EditIndex = e.RowIndex;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];


    TextBox PrStyle = (TextBox)row.FindControl("PrStyle");
    TextBox PrID = (TextBox)row.FindControl("PrID");

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;


    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update dt Set PrStyle='" + PrStyle + "',PrID='" + PrID + "'");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit? Code-only answers are considered very low quality (e.g. see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272))